# Is it waste of time to develop unmanaged C++ library which like .NET framework class library in design and architecture?

Tags: c++

There a lot of C++ class libraries either open source or commercial like MFC, ATL, SmartWin++,
QT. but none of them has the design and the architecture and the purity of .NET framework class library. What about the idea of implementing C++ library that is like .NET framework class library and provide the developers with a wide range of features and of course the library will be unmanaged and will wrap win32 API and COM

Comment: Yep, it's a waste of time. It's better to develop a C++ library with a better and cleaner design than .NET framework. C++ is a much more powerful language, and the current .NET design (and C++'s MFC, QT) are more like C-with-classes design.

Comment: "purity"? Hello language zealot.

Comment: Also you may try haxe

Comment: I had the same idea/desire. Actually, I think it would a great idea. You can't/shouldn't try and do it 100% as in .NET Framework, but sharing many similarities (e.g. in class names, method names, namespace names, method arguments, etc) would be great so that people won't have to learn 100 differently named methods in 100 different languages in order to perform the same action. I can assure you that I would use it if it plays nice with Visual Studio.

Comment: And if part of that was cross platform I would be the biggest fan. In my opinion STL (or whatever its name is nowadays) should be removed from the standard and from history - no matter how powerful it may be. Seeing the kinds of code that you write using this thing is enough to hate C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting question. But I believe it would be either a waste of time or not optimal to re-create the .NET BCL (base class library) for unmanaged C++. Why is that?

1. The C++ language is quite different from the .NET languages. This means that if you were to re-write the BCL for C++, you would optimally try to make the best use of C++. This would probably result in a fairly different framework design:

   - `IDisposable` and `Close` methods would not be necessary, since C++ offers deterministic freeing of releases and teardown of objects; something like `using` blocks, but far more generic. (The relevant C++ concepts are scopes, automatic storage, RAII, and smart pointer classes.) That is, a C++ BCL has the potential for a much more elegant design in this respect.
   - C++ templates are quite different from .NET generics. C++ also doesn't have delegates or events (even though you could probably mimick these). Reflection and run-time type and code generation also won't work easily with C++. Finally, C++ (before C++0x) doesn't support lambda functions. This means that the more modern additions to the BCL would probably have to look quite different in C++.
2. There are things in the BCL that have become obsolete, or if you designed the BCL today, it would turn out quite differently. Let's take `System.Reflection`. This part of the BCL was built before generics were introduced. If it was re-written from scratch today, chances are that reflection would take advantage of generics and therefore better type safety.
3. As you see, a new, C++ version of the BCL would very likely end up quite different than the .NET BCL it's based on; so you ought to wonder if it's even necessary to base such a new library on the .NET BCL at all. Do you even need to have one single framework, or is it easier in the end to develop separate libraries? One for networking, one for abstract data types, one for GUIs, one for reflection etc.

   - Separate libraries have the disadvantage that they possibly have no consistent API design. Therefore experience with one library doesn't help you at all learning another API.
   - Because of that, separate libraries can be easier to maintain. One can maintain the reflection library without having to concert each of one's actions with the GUI library maintainers, for example.
   - Separate libraries have the advantage that you can exchange one for the other if you find a cleaner, faster, or otherwise better replacement.
4. Even if someone wrote a C++ version of the BCL -- it would take much resources to maintain such a library in the long term, even more so when you consider that it should be platform-independent. Microsoft has this capacity and these resources. Would you, too?

The lure of one great library for everything is indeed the consistency of one API, and the fact that "everyone" would use it. But I think even if you wrote such a C++ BCL, you'll find it hard to reach almost every C++ programmer and convince them to your that library.

Comment: "also doesn't have delegates", tr1::function is essentially a delegate. and it has been available in boost for about 10 years already. Boost lambdas could also be used as lambdas. C++ is powerful enough to implement it in the language itself, although the syntax may be not so nice... Agree with everything else.

Comment: @ybungalobill: Thanks for the feedback. I wasn't certain about the status quo. I'm knew that delegates most likely *can* be "mimicked" in C++. Additionally, it would be fairly important that delegate types can be inferred by the compiler from a given function. Does `tr1::function` behave well in this respect?

Comment: @staks: IMO there is no mimicking, it's just the C++ way to accomplish this. I'm not sure I understand fully what you mean by "inferred", but I guess that yes: `void g(string); void f(function<void(string)>); ... f(g)`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume:
That you like C++ for performance reasons.
That you like .NET for productivity reasons.

You can try, but finally you will note that C++ will not supply the language constructions possible in managed languages (features as delegates, native interfaces, variance, lambda expressions, LINQ, etc), you can mimick but it will not look clean as you see in C# (you will need ugly preprocessor defines, and get up cryptic code, things that will not help code refactoring and other mantainance tasks).

You could check 2 alternatives:

- The alternative of use  [D (a new language)](http://dlang.org/). D is inspired on C++ performance and Java or.NET productivity. D compiler targets to native code, NOT Virtual Machine instruction set. But you need take off many editor tools, like Visual Studio's Intellisense and the native standard class library is under development yet.
- Or you can use  [AOT (Ahead of time compilation)](http://www.mono-project.com/AOT) or [NGEN (Native Image Generation)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf(v=VS.100).aspx). To compile .NET bytecode to native code. But it has some restrictions.

In both cases you get a modern language thinked for productivity and better performance than raw .NET platform without the cost of implement your own C++ BCL.